# C#: SQL FilterExpression - Missing Operand Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, search, sqldatasource

I am following the searchable gridview code listed [HERE](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ArticleVersion.aspx?aid=43018&av=60444) . I am having trouble with using the `FilterExpression`. I get the exception:

> Missing operand after 'Name' operator... When the exception occurs,
>   FilterExpression = " WHERE Name like 'spencer%'"

The exception occurs in the following code:

```
protected void BindSGVData()
        {
            //hfSearchText has the search string returned from the grid.
            if (hfSearchText.Value != "")
            {
                RidesSQL.FilterExpression = " WHERE " + hfSearchText.Value; //EXCEPTION HERE!
            }
            DataView dv = (DataView)RidesSQL.Select(new DataSourceSelectArguments());
            //hfSort has the sort string returned from the grid.
            if (hfSort.Value != "")
            {
                dv.Sort = hfSort.Value;
            }

            RideSGV.DataSource = dv;
            try
            {
                RideSGV.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                //If databinding threw exception bcoz current page index is > than available page index
                RideSGV.PageIndex = 0;
                RideSGV.DataBind();
            }
            finally
            {
                //Select the first row returned
                if (RideSGV.Rows.Count > 0)
                    RideSGV.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: @M.Babcock You sir are my hero! Lol, here is to not catching the obvious...I had changed it from editing the select command to adding a filter, and yup don't need the WHERE.. I was way too caught up with modifying the operands to notice. Gotta reply with an answer so I can give you a big fat green check mark! ( :

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
RidesSQL.FilterExpression = " WHERE " + hfSearchText.Value; //EXCEPTION HERE!
```

Should be:

```
RidesSQL.FilterExpression = hfSearchText.Value; // NO EXCEPTION HERE!
```

Comment: done +1 Sheinema pls mark this as your answer if this helps u